# Discern point of failure in multi-param query with node-sqlite3

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, node-sqlite3

In a Node.js server application I am trying to select a row through the `.get()` method filtering the result with a `WHERE` clause with multiple parameters.

```
function getRowByID(paramA, paramB, paramC) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        const query = 'SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE a=? AND b=? AND c=?'
        db.get(query, [paramA, paramB, paramC], (err, row) => {
            if (err) reject(err)
            else {
                // check contents of rows and resolve
            }
        })
    })
}
```

According to the node-sqlite3 API documentation if the result set is empty, the second parameter (`row`) of the callback is `undefined`. This unfortunately doesn't give me any information, how can I understand which parameter was the cause of the result being empty?
Could there be workarounds to the problem I am having, like - for example - splitting the query in different sequential promises?

Comment: Since the `WHERE` condition can be arbitrarily complex, the notion of a particular parameter being the "cause" doesn't really exist. Since your condition is fairly simple, you could try different combinations of a, b, and c. But there's no solution to this in the more general case.

Comment: Suppose you have 3 rows in the table that each match 2 of the parameters, but no row that matches all 3. There's no single parameter that's the cause of the result being empty.